# IIS Rewrite - redirect site to new domain capturing the language embedded in the URL

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting, regex-group, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to write a regex to redirect the URL to a new domain. I wrote IIS Rewrite rule for this:

```
<rule name="Redirect to new domain" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?my-www-en\.sites\.company\.net(\/([a-zA-Z]{2,3}-[a-zA-Z]{2,3}|en)\/?)?(.*$)" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://my-new-domain.com/en-us/{C:4}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

It works fine when the language is not added to the initial URL, however, some of the pages have the language added after the domain which results in double language appearance in the end URL.
So basically I would like to redirect things like:

```
my-www-en.sites.company.net/some-page/another/page/
www.my-www-en.sites.company.net/some-page/another/page/
my-www-en.sites.company.net/de-de/some-page/another/page/
www.my-www-en.sites.company.net/de-de/some-page/another/page/
my-www-en.sites.company.net/en/some-page/another/page/
```

to redirect to:

```
https://my-new-domain.com/en-us/some-page/another/page/
```

My current regex does not capture these groups correctly (even when it does while testing the regex in IIS rewrite) and I struggle to make it work. Right now everything gets redirected to the homepage instead to particular websites. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this rule. The regular expressions can match all urls above.

```
<rule name="test">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?my-www-en\.sites\.company\.net$" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(/.*)?(/some-page/another/page/)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="https://my-new-domain.com/en-us{C:2}" />
```

You can change rewrite to redirect.

Comment: We need it to work to any page on the website, not only one specific. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough about it. We also need to keep it as a redirect.

Comment: If you mean all pages and urls of `my-www-en.sites.company.net`, you just need to change `(/some-page/another/page/)` this part to the specific regular expression so that it can match all your other urls.

Comment: I don't know what your all urls are and their format. So I did not use regular expression.